# Looping through and modifying a list in unix

Tags: shell, unix, for-loop, sed, cat

I am trying to take the contents of a list `list1` and loop through them comparing them to another list generated by `finger`. When a name from `list1` is found in `finger` it should be removed from `list1`.

```
for i in $(cat list1); do
if finger | grep $i
    echo "$i is online"
    sed '/$i/d' <list1 >templist
    mv templist list1
fi
done
```

`list1` does not change. Once the script has run, the contents of `list1` are the same.
I think the problem has to do with the `cat` at the beginning but I'm not sure.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try double quotes:

```
sed "/$i/d" <list1 >templist
```

(There isn't actually any `$i` in the list.)

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to loop at all:

```
comm -23 <(sort list1) <(finger | sort) > tmpfile && 
mv list1 list1.bak &&
mv tmpfile list1
```

`comm -23 file1 file2` returns the lines in file1 that do not appear in file2. file1 and file2 must be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

If `list1` isn't massive (say, a few hundred items at most), you can do it like this:

```
finger | egrep -v "$(paste -sd'|' list1)" > templist && mv templist list1
```

How this works: `paste` turns the list into a pipe-separated list, which is inlined into the command using the `$(...)` construct, interpreted as a regexp by egrep, and negated with the `-v` flag to include only non-matching lines.

Answer (score 0):

Staying with the spirit of your original, I'd probably rewrite it along these lines to avoid that repetitive finger and sed-ing of the list among other things.

```
finger > fingerlist
while read aline ; do
    if grep "$aline" fingerlist > /dev/null ; then
        echo "$aline is online"
    else
        echo "$aline" > templist
    fi
done < list1
[ -s templist ] && mv -f templist list1
rm fingerlist
```